# Parsing structured text using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, multiline, string-matching

I am looking for 2 Regex expressions that will correctly parse the following block of lines (each line is a fixed length of 76 characters):

To give you an idea of the structure:

1. First 5 characters are the position (e.g. 00250)
2. Next 3 characters are the tag (e.g. SPS)
3. The text following this is free text which describes the function of the tag (this can be split over one or more lines, e.g. 'Sampling parameters for summary functional statistics)
4. The next 1 character can be either C (Conditional) or M (Mandatory)
5. The next 1 digit or more is the cardinality (e.g. 9999).
6. The plus signs and pipe characters indicate the grouping.

I require all 6 elements to be captured into groups.

**Example**

```
00250   SPS Sampling parameters for summary                               |
               functional                                                 |
               statistics                            C   99               |

00260   SPS Sampling parameters for summary                               |
               functional                                                 |
               statistics                            C   9999-------------+

00270   SPS Sampling parameters for summary                               |
               functional                                                 |
               statistics                            C   9---------------+|

00280   SPS Sampling parameters for summary                               |
               functional                                                 |
               statistics                            C   1--------------+||
```

There can be more than 1 plus (+) sign as shown in the sample above so the regex will need to take this into account.  Also, the pipe character (|) can appear more than once at the end of the line.

**The examples given above all show a description that spans three lines 'Sampling parameters for summary functional statistics' and each 'split' description needs to be appended to form a single string.**

I already have a working Regex for parsing the first line so I just need 2 others to parse lines 2 & 3.

This is what I have for line 2:

`(A)    ^\s{1,}(.+)\s{1,}\|$`

And line 3:

`(B)    ^\s{1,}(.+)\s(C|M)\s{1,}(\d+)(?:\s{1,}\|*|-{1,}(\+{1,})\|*)*$`

The problem is that Regex (A) is matching lines 2 & 3, when it should only match line 2.  Could someone show me the correct Regexes please so that I can correctly parse these lines?

**If it helps [here](http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trade/untdid/d14a/trmd/qality_c.htm) is an example of the full text I am parsing (section 4.3.1  Segment table).**

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am using C# so looking for a .NET solution.

Comment: @MikeClarke did you want something like this http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/7

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's very close.  Can the dashes be stripped out from group 7 as I do not require them? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeClarke: edit your post to show cases where the description part is on several lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a single pattern for the three lines and with named captures you can extract all informations you want from the block. This pattern use the verbose mode to be more readable:

```
(?<num>\d{5}) \s+ (?<letters>[A-Z]{3}) \s+ (?<desc>.+\S) \s+ \|
\s+
(?<func>\w+) \s+ \|
\s+
(?<stat>\w+) \s+ (?<letter>[A-Z]) \s+ (?<num2>\d+) [-\s]+ \+? \|{0,2}
```

[**demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cnum%3e%5cd%7b5%7d%29+%5cs%2b+%28%3f%3cletters%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%7d%29+%5cs%2b+%28%3f%3cdesc%3e.%2b%5cS%29+%5cs%2b+%5c%7c%0d%0a%5cs%2b%0d%0a%28%3f%3cfunc%3e%5cw%2b%29+%5cs%2b+%5c%7c%0d%0a%5cs%2b%0d%0a%28%3f%3cstat%3e%5cw%2b%29+%5cs%2b+%28%3f%3cletter%3e%5bA-Z%5d%29+%5cs%2b+%28%3f%3cnum2%3e%5cd%2b%29+%5b-%5cs%5d%2b+%5c%2b%3f%0d%0a%5c%7c%7b0%2c2%7d&i=00250+++SPS+Sampling+parameters+for+summary+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++functional+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++statistics++++++++++++++++++++++++++++C+++99+++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a%0d%0a00260+++SPS+Sampling+parameters+for+summary+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++functional+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++statistics++++++++++++++++++++++++++++C+++9999-------------%2b%0d%0a%0d%0a00270+++SPS+Sampling+parameters+for+summary+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++functional+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++statistics++++++++++++++++++++++++++++C+++9---------------%2b%7c%0d%0a%0d%0a00280+++SPS+Sampling+parameters+for+summary+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++functional+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7c%0d%0a+++++++++++++++statistics++++++++++++++++++++++++++++C+++1--------------%2b%7c%7c&o=x)

Comment: Can this be amended to work on a single line basis because my parser only reads one line of text at a time?

Comment: @MikeClarke: If you remove the two `\s+` you obtain the three patterns.

Comment: As the description is free text meaning it can contain letters, numbers and other characters your regex doesn't work when I add some non-alphabetic characters to the description.  I'm assuming that replacing `\w+` with `\.+` would work, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
([0-9]{5})\s*([\w\s]*\w)\s*[^\w]*(\w*)[^\w]*(\w*)\s*(C|M)\s*(\d+).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/9)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as it's expecting all three lines at the same time.  I need it to work on a per line basis.

Comment: but you said the description maybe separated by newlines.

Comment: The description could be on more than one line yes, but the parser reads one single line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a single gotcha regular expression, but I prefer to work on a per line basis. 
Regex should check if we have the leading digits or not and then feed the  line in a state machien sort of. State machien keep eating lines till a new leading digit pattern is satisfied or EOF.
When state machine finish "eating" lines you know the last line must contain at a column position "C" or "M", but you basically can parse that line in a fixed column length fashion.

Comment: That's basically what I have decided to.  I am currently creating separate regexes for each line type and then extract out the relevant groups from the regex into C# classes for the type of line parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by creating a regular expression for each line I want to capture and basically wrote a function called `getLineType(string line)`, which evaluates each regular expressions until it finds a match and returns a `LineType` enum identifying the type of line that was matched.

Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
private Regex _segmentTableLabel;
Regex SegmentTableLabel
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentTableLabel == null)
            _segmentTableLabel = new Regex( @"^4.3.1\s{1,}Segment table$" );

        return _segmentTableLabel;
    }
}

private Regex _headerOrDetailOrSummarySection;
Regex HeaderOrDetailOrSummarySection
{
    get
    {
        if (_headerOrDetailOrSummarySection == null)
            _headerOrDetailOrSummarySection = new Regex( @"^\s+(?:HEADER SECTION|DETAIL SECTION|SUMMARY SECTION)$" );

        return _headerOrDetailOrSummarySection;
    }
}

private Regex _blankLines;
Regex BlankLines
{
    get
    {
        if (_blankLines == null)
            _blankLines = new Regex( @"^\s+\|*" );

        return _blankLines;
    }
}

private Regex _segmentTableHeader;
Regex SegmentTableHeader
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentTableHeader == null)
            _segmentTableHeader = new Regex( @"^Pos\s{1,}Tag\s{1,}Name\s{1,}S\s{1,}R$" );

        return _segmentTableHeader;
    }
}

// reads: 00190       ---- Segment group 5  ------------------ C   200--------------+
private Regex _segmentGroupHeader;
Regex SegmentGroupHeader
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentGroupHeader == null)
            _segmentGroupHeader = new Regex( @"^(\d{1,5})\s{1,8}-{1,4}\sSegment group\s(\d{1,2})\s{1,}-{1,}\s(C|M)\s{1,3}(\d{1,})-{1,}(\++)\|*$" );

        return _segmentGroupHeader;
    }
}

// reads: 01420   DTM Date/time/period                         C   2------------+++++
private Regex _segmentLineFull;
Regex SegmentLineFull
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentLineFull == null)
            _segmentLineFull = new Regex( @"^(\d{1,5})\s{1,4}(\w+)\s(.{1,38})\s{1,3}(C|M)\s{1,3}(\d+)(?:-{0,}|\s*)(\+{0,})\|*$" );

        return _segmentLineFull;
    }
}

// reads: 00250   SPS Sampling parameters for summary                               |
private Regex _segmentLineFragmentFirst;
Regex SegmentLineFragmentFirst
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentLineFragmentFirst == null)
            _segmentLineFragmentFirst = new Regex( @"^(\d{1,5})\s{1,4}(\w+)\s(.{1,38})\s{1,24}\|$" );

        return _segmentLineFragmentFirst;
    }
}

// reads:                statistics                            C   1                |
private Regex _segmentLineFragmentLast;
Regex SegmentLineFragmentLast
{
    get
    {
        if (_segmentLineFragmentLast == null)
            _segmentLineFragmentLast = new Regex( @"^\s{1,15}(.{1,38})(C|M)\s{1,4}(\d{1,})\s{1,}\|+$" );

        return _segmentLineFragmentLast;
    }
}

...
...

switch (getLineType( line ))
{
    case Common.LineType.SegmentGroupHeader:
        // process segment group header
        break;

    case Common.LineType.SegmentLine:
        // process segment table line...
        break;

    case Common.LineType.SegmentLineBrokenFirst:
        // process a fragmented segment line...
        readNextLine = true;
        break;

    case Common.LineType.Ignore:
        // ignore line...
        break;

    default:
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( line ))
            errors.Add( string.Format( "Unknown line type {0}", line ) );

        break;
}

...
...

Common.LineType getLineType( string line )
{
    Common.LineType lineType = Common.LineType.Unknown;

    if (SegmentGroupHeader.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.SegmentGroupHeader;

    else if (SegmentLineFull.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.SegmentLine;

    else if (SegmentLineFragmentFirst.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.SegmentLineBrokenFirst;

    else if (SegmentLineFragmentLast.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.SegmentLineBrokenLast;

    else if (MessageStructureLabel.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.Ignore;

    else if (SegmentTableLabel.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.Ignore;

    else if (SegmentTableHeader.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.Ignore;

    else if (HeaderOrDetailOrSummarySection.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.Ignore;

    else if (BlankLines.IsMatch( line ))
        lineType = Common.LineType.Ignore;

    return lineType;
}
```